# How do I hide the closest element to the element that was clicked without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function that changes the `src` attribute of an icon when this one is clicked.
I also want it to hide the closest icon of the class `fave_icon`. I tried the following but it's not working:

```
function trash(event, trashcan){
    event.stopPropagation();
    if (trashcan.getAttribute('src') == "Iconos/tacho.png")
    {
        trashcan.src = "Iconos/warning.png"; //this works ok
        var heart = trashcan.closest(".fave_icon");
        heart.style.visibility = "hidden"            
    }
}
```

Basically I want to hide the closest element with class `fave_icon`  to `trashcan`.

[image]

On the HTML I have this several times:

```
<button class="accordion">
  <div>
    <img src="Iconos/heart.png" onclick="fav(event,this);" alt="Fave" class="fave_icon">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="Iconos/tacho.png" onclick="trash(event,this);" alt="Delete" class="delete_icon">
  </div>
</button>
```

Comment: Depends what you mean by *"closest"*. Please provide a [mcve] to minimize guessing

Comment: Don't post image ...... please add HTML.

Comment: I posted some part of the HTML, is that ok or should I add more? I mean that part is also inside another few divs

Comment: many options with js, what about .next() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `fave_icon` is a class then you have to place dot (`.`) before the class name as part of the selector.

Change `var heart = trashcan.closest("fave_icon");`

To

`var heart = trashcan.closest(".fave_icon");`

Based on the code and HTML you have provided you can do something like the following:

```js
function trash(event, trashcan){
 event.stopPropagation();
 if (trashcan.getAttribute('src') == "Iconos/tacho.png"){
    trashcan.src = "Iconos/warning.png"; //this works ok
    var heart = trashcan.closest('button').querySelector('.fave_icon');
    heart.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">
  <div>
    <img src="Iconos/heart.png" onclick="fav(event,this);" alt="Fave" class="fave_icon">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="Iconos/tacho.png" onclick="trash(event,this);" alt="Delete" class="delete_icon">
  </div>
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks that surely was a problem but it's still not working

Comment: @Stackoverflowed, please update the question with required HTML...thanks.

Comment: Ok I just did it

Comment: @Stackoverflowed, you are most welcome...glad to know that you are able to get going......happy programming.

Answer (score 0):

From the trash icon, you go up a level to the div, select the `previousElementSibling` to get the heart's div, and then go down a level to the heart image itself.

Because the element is already included in the event target, you don't need to pass `this`. Or, even better, if you select the trash image first, you can avoid `this` entirely and use explicit variable names, which are easier to understand and debug.

But inline event handlers are essentially `eval` inside HTML markup - they're bad practice and result in poorly factored, hard-to-manage code. Seriously consider attaching your events with JavaScript, instead, eg: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener

Another problem is that `button`s should not have closing tags. Use a container element instead, like a `div`.

So, try something like this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('img[src="Iconos/tacho.png"]').forEach(img => {
  img.onclick = () => {
    const heartImg = img.parentElement.previousElementSibling.children[0];
    heartImg.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  };
});
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <div>
    <img src="Iconos/heart.png" alt="Fave" class="fave_icon">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="Iconos/tacho.png" alt="Delete" class="delete_icon">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add a class to the clicked element and use **the general sibling combinator** if the two items are adjacent.

```js
document.getElementById("hide")
  .addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    event.target.classList.add('active');
  }, false);
```

```css
#hide.active~.element {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#hide {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion {
  padding: 15px;
  background: lightgrey;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

.accordion div {
  color: black;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/icono/1.3.0/icono.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="accordion">
  <div class="icono-trash" id="hide"></div>
  <div class="element icono-heart"></div>
</div>
```